# how to update the active column

Tags: php

Hello how to update the active column in the table my code seems not working

db.php 
`public function active($table, $id, $fields, $activecode){
            $set = '';
            $x = 1;

```
        foreach($fields as $name => $value){
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if($x < count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id} AND activecode = {$activecode}";

        if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()){
            return true;
        }

        //return false;
    }`
```

activate.php

`require_once 'core/init.php';

```
if(Input::exists()){

if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))){

        $validate   = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'id'  => array('required' => 'true'),
            'activecode'  => array('required' => 'true')

        ));

        if($validation->passed()){
            $user = new User();

                $user->active(array(

                    'active'      => 1
                ));

                Session::flash('success', 'success.');
                Redirect::to('index.php');
            }else{

                echo "error";
            }
        }else{
            pre($validation->errors());
        }


   }`
```

activation link
Activate.php?active=.$activecode.&id=.$id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$set .= "{$name} = '{$value}'";
```

Also "$this" needs to be a mysqli object and the format is:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$mysqli->query($sql);
if(!$mysqli->error){
```

[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: if you echo $sql, what is the output?

Comment: here is the full code DB.php => https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/playback/XWOYTUNPPQ init.php => https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/playback/UODTAEPFNH activate.php => https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/playback/XXTXERDRDZ thank you for your answer @Chad Skiles